# I don't understand something in memory addressing

Tags: memory-management, x86, x86-16

I have a very simple (n00b) question.

> A 20-bit external address bus gave a 1 MB physical address space (2^20
>   = 1,048,576).(Wikipedia)

Why 1 MByte?

```
2^20 = 1,048,576 bit = 1Mbit = 128KByte not 1MB
```

I misunderstood something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have 20 bits you can address up to `2^20`. This is your **range**, not the number of bits.

I.e. if you have 8 bits your range is up to 255 (unsigned) not 2^8 bits.

So with 20 bits you can address up to 2^20 bytes i.e. 1MB

I.e. with 20 bits you can represent addresses from 0 up to `2^20` = 1,048,576. I.e. you can reference up to 1MB of memory.

Answer (score 2):

`1 << 20` addresses, that is `1,048,576` bytes addressable. Hence, 1 MB physical address space.

Comment: Take a look at memory dump. You have some byte at address `[00000]`, then what about going to `[00001]`? It is a new byte there, not just bit.

Answer (score 2):

Because the smallest addressable unit of memory (in general - some architectures have small bit-addressable pieces of memory) is the byte, not the bit. That is, each address refers to a byte, rather than to a bit.

Why, you ask? Direct access to individual bits is almost never needed - and if you need it, you can still load the surrounding byte and get the bit with bit masks and shifts. Increasing the bits per address allows you to address more memory with the same address range.

Note that a byte doesn't *have* to be 8 bit, strictly speaking, though it's ubiquitous by now. But regardless of the byte size, you're grouping bits together to be able to handle larger quantities of them.